# LINQ C# data query grabbing bottom element of a database and check it

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datetime

my code
I need to grab the bottom element (most recent) entry into my database and see if it was over 1 hour ago, the type of ObservationTime is DateTime. I keep getting an error saying that "Sequence contains more than one element" for my var mWeathers. I think it has to do with the way I'm orderby descending but i cant figure it out. Thanks

```
    [OperationContract]
    public bool LeastOneHour()
    {

        DataClassesDBDataContext db = new DataClassesDBDataContext();
        var mWeathers = (from weathertable in db.WeatherTables 
                         orderby weathertable.ObservationTime descending 
                         select weathertable.ObservationTime).Single();
        DateTime lastTime = Convert.ToDateTime(mWeathers).AddHours(1);
        if ( lastTime <= DateTime.Now)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Single()` says there *must* be one element in the result, and if there are more than one, throw an exception.  What you're likely looking for is `First()`, or `FirstOrDefault()` if there's a chance there will be no results at all (in which case null is returned)

If you can be guaranteed that there will always be an element, try this:

```
DateTime lastDate = db.WeatherTables.OrderByDescending (w => w.ObservationTime).Select(w => w.ObservationTime).First();

return lastDate.AddHours(1) <= DateTime.Now;
```

Otherwise something like

```
DateTime? lastDate = db.WeatherTables.OrderByDescending (w => w.ObservationTime).Select(w => w.ObservationTime).FirstOrDefault();

return lastDate.HasValue ? lastDate.AddHours(1) <= DateTime.Now : false;
```

Assuming of course ObservationDate is declared as DateTime?

Comment: does the w => w reverse the table? Sorry im a noobie to C# and silverlight but it works thanks a bunch

Comment: ?? `.OrderByDescending (w => w.ObservationTime)` sorts the table by ObservationTime in descending order.  Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 4):

Since your query returns more than one element and you want to take the first element from those results, use `First()` instead of `Single()`:

```
var mWeathers = (from weathertable in db.WeatherTables 
                 orderby weathertable.ObservationTime descending 
                 select weathertable.ObservationTime).First();
```

Or if there's a chance that the query will produce no results, you should use `FirstOrDefault()`:

```
var mWeathers = (from weathertable in db.WeatherTables 
                 orderby weathertable.ObservationTime descending 
                 select weathertable.ObservationTime).FirstOrDefault();
```

And if you're not against making some other changes, you could make your code cleaner and less verbose:

```
var mWeathers = db.WeatherTables
                  .OrderByDescending(w => w.ObservationTime)
                  .First(); // or FirstOrDefault()

return Convert.ToDateTime(mWeathers).AddHours(1) <= DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 4):

As well as the other (perfectly valid) answers you've already been given, you may want to consider:

```
DateTime lastTime = db.WeatherTables.Max(table => table.ObservationTime);
```

or

```
DateTime? lastTime = db.WeatherTables.Max<DateTime?>(t => t.ObservationTime);
```

The latter form *may* cope with an empty table (where the first won't). It would be fine in LINQ to Objects, but I always hesitate to say that something *will* work in LINQ to SQL without trying it first :)

Comment: Gah - I thought it was later across the pond.  I guess I'll go find something else to do until UK nightfall :)    +1 though - that's slick

Comment: :) - no complaints - on page 212 of your book.  Picking up some wonderful tricks; never would have imagined using the coalescing operator like you did showed.